# Carousel with percentage navbar (pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I need to show a percentage navbar under my carousel like this:
[image: Navbar example]

When i click on my arrow, the grey space move on the right or on the left, based on the carousel length.
I am using pure javascript, no bootstrap carousel or other libraries.

Comment: "*I am using pure javascript*"; Please show us! We can't help without the code! I'd recommend reading [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I is difficult to answer not seeing your page code. But I suppose (if that grey line is 'elem' in js)

```
arrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
      elem.style.transition = '0.5s all'; //to make the smooth change strip length 
      elem.style.width = +elem.style.width.slice(0, elem.style.width.length-2) + stepWidth +'px';
    })
```

may help you.